# Why can I not check SharedPreferences reference object is null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

Is the following allowed ?

```
SharedPreferences prefInfo = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LogonData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (prefInfo != null) {
     String savedName = prefInfo.getString("myEmailID", "NO DATA");  
}
```

saw that it's better to check first if the `SharedPreferences`object is not null before do `getString()`, but I am curious why I can not check the `prefInfo` reference first then get the data ?  I hate fixing things without understanding why ?

My app crashed with `NullPointerException` on the first line

```
SharedPreferences prefInfo = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LogonData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think the `getActivity()` return null, so that's why it crashes on the first line

Comment: It would appear that getActivity() is null, which probably indicates that you are doing something wrong.  From where in your code are you calling this?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see my error now thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're being told to get the string then check for null is that SharedPreferences is an interface for accessing preference data, not a class holding data itself. So, SharedPreferences is just a means for you to access data should it be available. It does not guarantee that such data is actually present.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

As for your particular error, since you're calling a method that's just returning an interface, you must be calling that method on a null object. Your getActivity() is failing.

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences()` will always return a `SharedPreference` with the associated name of 1st string param. it will never return `null`

you are getting `null` from `getActivity()` for sure, thats why you are getting `NullPointerException`. from which callback method of the fragment, you are calling/executing this code block?